# Not sure what's wrong here but guessing I need to change the path

Tags: python, django

**main_urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path , include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'' , include("learning_logs.urls", 'app_name'))
]
```

**second_urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #Home page
    path(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]

app_name = 'learning_log'
```

**views.py:**
from django.shortcuts import render

```
def index(request):
    return render(request , 'learning_logs/index.html')
```

result:
[djangowebapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faraY.png)

Comment: Is there an additional comma in your urlpatterns list in second_urls.py or is it me ?

Answer (score 2):

You are using [`path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#django.urls.path) syntax that is different from old [`url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#url) and should be used without regex

```
path('', views.index, name='index'),
```

if you want to use regex paths you could use [`re_path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#django.urls.path)

```
re_path(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```